# Turning off audio background mode triggers kMIDINotPermitted even though background audio is not needed

Tags: audiokit, background-mode

I've got a `MIDISampler` that is triggered by a `MIDICallbackInstrument`. I don't want my app to work in the background since it is an interactive ear training game. Unfortunately if I disable "Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture" I get the following error:

> CheckError.swift:CheckError(_:):176:kMIDINotPermitted: Have you enabled the audio background mode in your ios app?

Also the sampler plays fixed pitch sine waves instead of samples.

The solution would be to just turn on the audio background mode though it is not needed. Everything works fine, no errors. Unfortunately Apple is rejecting my app in that case since it's not using background audio.

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need background audio enabled for MIDISampler. As long as your app is stopping the audio engine when the app moves into the background, they should allow it. I would explain your use case and appeal the rejection.

Comment: Thank you! They accepted my submission today. I had to explain and show my app in a video to convince the App Review team. In the video I also passed along the information you recommended.

Comment: That's awesome! Congrats on the app launch!